# Correct way to create an ajax request on Quasar Framework

Tags: vuejs2, quasar

Is adding `<script>` tag including jquery, then calling `$.post` or `$.get` inside `.vue` is the correct way?

Comment: have a look at vue-resource, axios, or the fetch api

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Install `jquery` using npm

```
npm i --save jquery
```

Then on `.vue` file, it can be used as usual:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
let $ = jQuery
$.post( ... )
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery, Quasar has axios injected by default .. https://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-plugins.html#Axios

Answer (score 6):

There is a section on the official Docs which is related to this:

- http://quasar-framework.org/guide/ajax-requests.html

Mainly, it recommends using Vue Resource plugin for VueJs or Axios.

> Quasar recommends using Vue Resource plugin for VueJs or Axios. These
>   package are not provided by default so you will have to npm install
>   them and import them from src/main.js.

---

#### Axios. ([More info](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios))

```
npm install axios --save
```

Example:

```
axios.get('https://someurl/api/?something=1').then(response => {
        ...
       }).catch(e => {
         ...
       })
```

---

#### Vue Resource ([More info](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource))

```
npm install vue-resource --save
```

Example:

```
{
   this.$http.get('/someurl/api/?something=1')
     .then(response => {

        //... response.body;

      }, response => {
        ...
      });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use vue-resource or axios packages for ajax request in Vue app, instead of jQuery....

[Quasar guide](http://quasar-framework.org/guide/ajax-requests.html)